# ES6 Map Reduce array flatten with mapping and padding from Redux state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, mapreduce

I am writing a React/Redux app using ES6 and I want an efficient way to map this data:

```
[
  {total: 50, label: "C1"}, 
  {total: 120, label: "C2"}, 
  {total: 220, label: "C4"}
]
```

To something like below:

```
[
  {50, "Category 1"}, 
  {120, "Category 2"}, 
  {0, "Category 3"}, 
  {220, "Category 4"}
  {0, "Category 5"}, 
]
```

The key being that it flattens the original array and relabels the label values and also pads out the missing keys.

I can do this with some ugly looking JS iterating over it but I'm struggling to get this to work with a simple and elegant reduce arrow function mechanism which I'm sure is possible.

Comment: `something like below` ...is it javascript?

Comment: That "something like below" should probably be an array of arrays and not an array of ...

Comment: {"50": "Category 1"} or [50, "Category 1"]?

Comment: Why do you need the "Category X" string, if that can be inferred from the position in the final array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a *hashtable* to pad out the missing keys to an *array of arrays* - see demo below:

```js
var arr = [{total: 50, label: "C1"},{total: 120, label: "C2"},{total: 220, label: "C4"}];

// create a hash table first
var hash = arr.reduce(function(p,c){
  var key = c.label.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
  p[key] = c;
  // largest key
  p['count'] = (+key > (p['count'] || 0)) ? +key : p['count'];
  return p;
}, Object.create(null));

// accumulate the result
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < hash['count']; i++) {
  var el = hash[i + 1] || {};
  result.push([el.total || 0, 'Category '+ (i+1)]);
}
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top: 0;max-height: 100%!important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.map()`.

```js
var foo = [{
    total: 50,
    label: "C1"
  },
  {
    total: 120,
    label: "C2"
  },
  {
    total: 220,
    label: "C4"
  }
];

var flatFoo = foo.map((obj) => {
  return [
    obj.total,
    `${obj.label.substr(0, 1)}ategory ${obj.label.substr(1, 1)}`
  ];
});

console.log(flatFoo);
```

Comment: And the missing items with value `0` ?

Comment: You need to indicate the length of your array somewhere, if you do that a ternary could handle the conditional to determine if the index and label number line up.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options...

```js
const data = [
  {total: 50, label: "C1"}, 
  {total: 120, label: "C2"}, 
  {total: 220, label: "C4"}
];

const stripChars = s => (s || '').replace(/[a-z]/i, '');


function fillTo(limit, data) {

  return Array
    .from({length: limit}, (_, i) => (
      data.find(o => stripChars(o.label) == i) ||
      { total: 0, label: `C${i}` }
    ))
  ;
}


const toMap = data => data.reduce(
  (res, $1) => Object.assign(res, {
    [$1.total]: `Category ${stripChars($1.label)}`
  }), Object.create(null)
);

const pairwise = data => data.map(
  $1 => [$1.total, `Category ${stripChars($1.label)}`]
);

console.log('fillTo', fillTo(6, data));
console.log('toMap', toMap(data));
console.log('pairwise', pairwise(data));

/**
 * 1. fill the array
 * 2. chose your transformer 
 * 
 * const d = fillTo(6, data);
 * console.log(pairwise(d));
**/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first sort original array to get min and max value and then use loops to add missing elements.

```js
var data = [
  {total: 220, label: "C14"},
  {total: 50, label: "C3"}, 
  {total: 120, label: "C10"}, 
  {total: 220, label: "C7"}
]


data.sort((a, b) => a.label.slice(1) - b.label.slice(1))
var result = [];

data.forEach(function(e, i) {
  var n = e.label.slice(1);
  var next = data[i + 1]
  result.push([e.total, 'Category ' + n]);

  if (next) {
    for (var j = n; j < +(next.label.slice(1) - 1); j++) {
      result.push([0, 'Category ' + (+j + 1)])
    }
  }
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4))
```